# Как поулучить элементы каталога из json строки?1с-Bitrix

Tags: php, json, битрикс

**Дано**:

1. Сервер под управлением centos 6 , там я развернул малый битрикс
2. Также есть http://gw.open.1688.com:80/openapi/param2/1/cn.ali... запрос по которому мы получаем список элементов с сайта **1688.com**

**Необходимо**, на основе полученных данных, в торговом каталоге сайта создать раздел с элементами. Элемент должен содержать цену, свойства, изображения, одним словом все, что есть в выгрузке.

**Например**, я на чистом битриксе сделаю компонент "КАТАЛОГ", там выведу раздел с элементами, как я понял надо написать какой то скрипт, который берет этот json, проходит по нему циклом и кидает данные через api функции в базу, то бишь после того как скрипт отработал у меня в базе будут товары
и строку мусолить больше не нужно?

Вообщем, ребят подскажите плиз как подступиться? как написать этот скрипт? Как правильно вывести каталог?, желательно подробно, с примерами кода если можно) Или документацией

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у битрикса есть класс Bitrix\Main\Web\HttpClient
его можно использовать для получения строки json и затем декодировать

```
use Bitrix\Main\Web\HttpClient;

$httpClient = new HttpClient($options);
$httpClient->get($url);
$res = $httpClient->getResult();

try {
    $ar = json_decode($httpClient->getResult(), true);
} catch (\Exception $e){

}

if(is_array($ar))
{
   # если данные непосредственно в $ar
   foreach($ar => $product)
   {
      # добавление в базу 
   }
}
```

добавление элемента в инфоблок
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/add.php

```
$el = new CIBlockElement;

$PROP = array();
$PROP[12] = 11;

$arLoadProductArray = Array(
  "MODIFIED_BY"    => $USER->GetID(), // элемент изменен текущим пользователем
  "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => false,          // элемент лежит в корне раздела
  "IBLOCK_ID"      => 18,
  "PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $PROP,
  "NAME"           => "Элемент",
  "ACTIVE"         => "Y",            // активен
  "PREVIEW_TEXT"   => "текст для списка элементов",
  "DETAIL_TEXT"    => "текст для детального просмотра",
  "DETAIL_PICTURE" => CFile::MakeFileArray($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/image.gif")
  );

if($PRODUCT_ID = $el->Add($arLoadProductArray))
{
   # добавляем информацию для каталога
   # https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/ccatalogproduct/add.php

   # цены 
   # https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/cprice/add.php

}
```

для вывода можно воспользоваться стандартным компонентов bitrix:catalog

Answer (score 2):

Курлом (curl) выгребаешь json, полученные данные прогоняешь через json_decode(); 
Затем добавляешь полученные данные элементов в нужный тебе инфоблок с помощью [CIBlockElement::Add()](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/add.php). После чего выводишь все полученное добро в нужном компоненте.